# Can't bind to 'uploader' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, typescript

i am trying to use [this](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload) library to upload files in the angular2 CR5 typescript. I am using  angular  `"version": "1.0.0-beta.16"`

So, first i

```
npm i ng2-file-upload --save
```

in the component i have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload';

// const URL = '/api/';
const URL = 'https://evening-anchorage-3159.herokuapp.com/api/';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple-demo',
  templateUrl: './simple-demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./simple-demo.component.css']
})
export class SimpleDemoComponent {
  public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL});
  public hasBaseDropZoneOver:boolean = false;
  public hasAnotherDropZoneOver:boolean = false;

  public fileOverBase(e:any):void {
    this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
  }

  public fileOverAnother(e:any):void {
    this.hasAnotherDropZoneOver = e;
  }
}
```

a part of the html side of component is:

```
          <div ng2FileDrop
                 [ngClass]="{'nv-file-over': hasBaseDropZoneOver}"
                 (fileOver)="fileOverBase($event)"
                 [uploader]="uploader"
                 class="well my-drop-zone">
                Base drop zone
            </div>
```

and it complains with:

```
Can't bind to 'uploader' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("s': hasAnotherDropZoneOver}"
                 (fileOver)="fileOverAnother($event)"
                 [ERROR ->][uploader]="uploader"
                 class="well my-drop-zone">
                Another drop zone
"): AppComponent@33:17
```

Comment: Got it working ? If yes , can you please share solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to update my angular to the latest version.

and then add the following to the `app.module` file:

```
import { FileUploadModule } from "ng2-file-upload";
//...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        //...,
        FileUploadModule
    ],
    declarations: [],
    providers: []
})
export class ObjektinfoModule {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

sometimes you need to use (uploader) instead of square brackets [uploader] to bind the property correctly. Very strange but fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was not only the Import but also in template also:

Try with the below (uploader) initializing in component.html file.

instead of  `[uploader]="uploader":`

```
             <div ng2FileDrop
                   [ngClass]="{'nv-file-over': hasBaseDropZoneOver}"
                   (fileOver)="fileOverBase($event)"
                   [uploader]="uploader"
                   (onFileDrop)="onFileSelected($event)"
                   class="well my-drop-zone">
                  Base drop zone
              </div>
```

Add `(uploader)="uploader":`

```
                <div ng2FileDrop
                   [ngClass]="{'nv-file-over': hasBaseDropZoneOver}"
                   (fileOver)="fileOverBase($event)"
                   (uploader)="uploader"
                   (onFileDrop)="onFileSelected($event)"
                   class="well my-drop-zone">
                  Base drop zone
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simply to import the FIleUploadModule into the main module.

```
import { FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload'
...
imports: [
...
FileUploadModule
],
```